# Test React/Redux component with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs

I am trying to test a React component with Redux using Jest:

```
// components/MyComponent/index.js

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    const { someBoolean } = this.props;
    if (someBoolean === false) {
      this.props.myFunction().then(() => myHelperFunction());
    }
  }

  render = () => {
    return <div>Something</div>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { someBoolean: state.someBoolean };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  myFunction,
})(MyComponent);
```

In the component, if `props.myBoolean == false`, will call `myFunction` from this Redux module:

```
// Redux/modules/MyModule/actions/someActions.js

export const someAction = (type) => (dispatch) => dispatch({ type });
export const myFunction = () => someAction("SOME_ACTION");
```

I have a helper function somewhere else:

```
// tools/helpers.js

export const myHelperFunction = () => { // do stuff }
```

Now I want to test that, if `MyComponent` receives `someBoolean` as `false`, it calls `myFunction` and then `myHelperFunction`:

```
// components/MyComponent/index.test.js

jest.mock("Redux/modules/MyModule/actions/someActions.js", () => ({
  myFunction: jest.fn(),
}));

jest.mock("tools/helpers.js", () => ({
  myHelperFunction: jest.fn(),
}));

it("should call myFunction when myBoolean is false", () => {
  const initialState = {
    myBoolean: false,
  };

  const holder = mountWithTheme(mockRedux(<MyComponent />, [], initialState));

  expect(myFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(myHelperFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

But no matter what I do, it wont pass. What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I'd suggest not to use jest's magic for mocking imports. Instead of that you can simplify tests by testing dumb components only and passing all functions as props.

```
it("should call myFunction when myBoolean is false", () => {
  const props = {
    myBoolean: false,
    myFunction: jest.fn(),
    myHelperFunction: jest.fn()
  };

  const holder = mountWithTheme(<MyComponent {...props}/>);

  expect(myFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(myHelperFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

And refactor a bit your component:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    const { someBoolean } = this.props;
    if (someBoolean === false) {
      this.props.myFunction().then(() => this.props.myHelperFunction());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question is with the provided class.